# Why my react application don't send the cookie to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js, jwt

I have been developing an application with front-end with Next.js and back-end with node js, I use JWT and I send the token as part of the cookie, the problem start that when I run both client and server in locahost it works fine, but when I upload the server to a cloud service, the request doesn't send the cookie.

I'am using cookies-js in the client side to set the cookie, like this:

```
Cookies.set('x-token', token, { sameSite: 'none', secure: true });
```

I also have configured axios like this:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

const nazcaApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NAZCA_API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default nazcaApi;
```

My server code looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import dbConnection from './database/config';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

import { AuthRoutes, ToursRoutes, UserRoutes } from './routes';

const app = express();
dbConnection();

app.use(function (_req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

//Routes
app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', UserRoutes);
app.use('/api/tours', ToursRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor corriendo en puerto ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

And I get the cookie inside of a middleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';

interface TokenPayload extends JwtPayload {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const validateJWT = (_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = _req.cookies['x-token'];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: 'No hay token en la petición',
    });
  }

  try {
    const { id, name } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_JWT_SEED || '') as TokenPayload;

    _req.body.id = id;
    _req.body.name = name;

    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: 'Token no válido',
    });
  }
};

export default validateJWT;
```